# Enable angular.json schema for WebStorm 2020.1.2

Tags: angular-cli, webstorm, jsonschema, angular-schematics

For some reason angular.json (`@angular/cli@9.1.0`) schema is not loaded by WebStorm 2020.1.2. This makes customizing angular.json much harder. This was working in older WebStorm version.

I tried adding the angular.json schema manually, still no success there. Check the attached image bellow.

How to make angular.json schema work in WebStorm 2020.1.2?

[image: WebStorm Settings]

Comment: @MikeB. found it in the globe button added it from there, bu still I don't have any hinting inside angular.json

Comment: Please find below the full answer, hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an Angular JSON schema in IDEA/WebStorm 2020.2:

1. Go to: **File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs | JSON Schema Mappings**.
2. In the upper left corner, click on <kbd>+</kbd> to add a new schema.
3. Provide a schema name.
4. In **Schema file or URL**, set: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular-cli/master/packages/angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json`.
5. In **Schema version**, set **JSON Schema version 7**.
6. On the right side of the **Settings** window, click on <kbd>+</kbd> to add all JSON files, which should be processed with this JSON schema:
   [image: JSON Schema Mappings]
7. Press **Apply**.

That's all! Now IDEA/WebStorm will process your JSONs with the Angular JSON schema including the code suggestions and schema validation:

[image: A schema-processed angular.json]

It's also possible to assign a JSON schema via the bottom right corner, click on **No JSON schema** and select the schema name, you've provided in the step #3:

[image: Angular JSON Schema]

Comment: thx for the fast reply, yes I see it in the list and added it from the URL but the problem is that this apparently does not do anything. When I open angular.json still I don't get any hinting. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @MikeB.thank you this worked my mistake was I did no added path to the angular.json file inside my project, assumed that webstorm will figure out automatically :) to link angular.json to the provided schema. But your tutorial rocks !!!

Comment: @Hivaga, since in one project there could be multiple JSONs of different types/schemas, IDE requires a manual assignment.